# Dropdown defaulted value and still show invalid validator

Tags: flutter, validation, dropdown

I've created a dropdown with a validator, and the dropdown value defaults during init. But the validator still shows invalid errors.

The value is populated and showed on the form during init state, and the error gone after do a selection on the dropdown.

Below are some code snipping

```
String _genderSelectedItem;

setInit() async {

setState(() {
  _insitutionDropdownMenuItems =
      buildDropDownMenuItems(_insitutionDropdownItems);
  if (currentUsr.gender != null && currentUsr.gender != "") {
    _genderSelectedItem = currentUsr.gender;
  }
});
```

}

```
    Container(
                  color: Color(0xfff5f5f5),
                  child: new DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Gender',
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.female_rounded),
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
                      value: _genderSelectedItem,
                      items: _dropdownMenuItems,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _genderSelectedItem = value;
                        });
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null) return "Please Select Gender";
                        return null;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

[image]

Comment: replace `value: _uniSelectedItem,` with `value: _genderSelectedItem,` and give it a try. Else add code for where you assign initial value for `_uniSelectedItem`

Comment: sorry, i had showed the wrong code snipping previously just updated the correct one